# Is it bad to ask for code samples?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, help-improvement

Yesterday I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39710808/kivy-screenmanager-code-example) where I'm asking for the source code of that GIF image. However, I've got `-3` votes on it.

I read the rules again this morning, but I get to see what I did wrong (or where they say I can't ask for source code).

What did I do wrong?

Comment: One of the reasons of downvoting is that you can simply find your answer by googling within 1 minute

Comment: 'googling within 1 minute' did not return any result, sadly. That's why I asked that question.
I did search on that site the whole day, but not code for that gif was found. Thus, I asked.

Comment: I always found very valuable to ear all opinions... even the "most opinionated"... and then made may judgment... also the comments over the "more opinionated" questions from other users are always welcome knowledge...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is bad. This close-reason fits:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

I don't see any way to fix it, so my recommendation is removing it completely.
See it as a learning experience.

Comment: I always found very valuable to ear all opinions... even the "most opinionated"... and then made may judgment... also the comments over the "more opinionated" questions from other users are always welcome knowledge...

Comment: @ZEE *All* opinions? Or just those from a trusted or at least known group which is not too big to involve it in an in-depth face-to-face discussion, and which also know you and your task quite well? Anyway, there are other sites geared to open-ended discussions.